# Can I safely uninstall episodes I've finished?

Tags: life-is-strange-before-the-storm

Can I safely uninstall episodes I've finished in Life is Strange: Before the Storm? Additional episodes are marked as DLC and are just staying there even though I won't play them again and I'll have to wait a month (or longer) to get the next one. I can just uninstall the DLC without actually removing the whole game but will it make me lose my progress, choices and graffiti collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been over 2 years and you've probably finished the game by now, but I figured I'd answer the question for you for the sake of completeness!

Yes, you can disable the DLCs (including the Farewell bonus story DLC) and your saved game will be untouched. I disabled everything and the game still allowed me to see all the choices I'd made on that save file.

Also, if you wanted to back up your save or copy it to another machine, they're located at:

`C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\LocalLow\Square Enix\Life Is Strange_ Before The Storm`

I don't think uninstalling the game will delete that directory anyway, but if you did back it up, you can just uninstall the entire game without worries.